# Permutation or Combination or

Tags: permutations, combinations

Can this question be answered unambiguously? Or does it depend on the meaning of "committee"?

> > Identify the following as a permutation or a combination: 
> >     Selecting a committee of politicians.

Comment: Politicians has no order whatsoever. So you do not care about an order. So it is a combination. Notice that if they ask for politicians with some exact positions it will be different.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My daughter wrote combination, but her teacher says permutation. It is hard for me to understand why the answer is so clear-cut just from the wording in the question.

Comment: It's a little ambiguous; this is a common problem in combinatorics and probability, where slight changes in wording can change the answer drastically. But I think it's pretty standard for "committee" to mean "subset" (no order), so it's a combination.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: In reality, we have the liberty of asking for clarification from whoever asked us the question or deciding ourselves if we are the one who asked the question on whether or not order is relevant.  In related problems in probability, *either* is generally useful and the decision is purely out of convenience.  For example, in asking the question "What is the probability of being dealt five spades from a shuffled standard deck of playing cards?" you could see the answer as $\dfrac{\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$ or as $\dfrac{13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}$